# generate jwt token from spring boot for an angular application

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, authentication, jwt

my problem is about jwt token-based authentication with spring boot in backend and angular in frontend, so to do that I developed two filters in my spring security configuration , one to issue tokens and the other to validate them , inside the filter that issues tokens : the request to "/login" endpoint will contain user details like password and username so the filter can authenticate the user and issue token in return , and that's my problem, I can't see any other way to let the authentication operation until we get to the controller where I have to make that specific endpoint .

```java
@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {

try {

~~// 1. Get credentials from request
~~UserCredentials creds = new ~~ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), ~~UserCredentials.class);

// 2. Create auth object (contains credentials) which will be used by auth manager
~~UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(creds.getUsername(),creds.getPassword(), Collections.emptyList());

// 3. Authentication manager authenticate the user, and use ~~UserDetialsServiceImpl::loadUserByUsername() method to load the user.
    return authManager.authenticate(authToken);

~~} catch (IOException e) {
~~~~~~throw new RuntimeException(e);
 }
}
```

My friends I want you to advise me if what I already do is good or not, and how the best way to perform that inside a controller or directly inside the filter?
Thanks (please forgive my English)

expected result :

```
@PostMapping("/login")
public void method(@RequestBody MyUser myUser){
// perform authentication and issue token for my front app
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better if you follow the below.

1)ISSUE of Token -  it should be done after filter level, I mean you should validate your HTTP requests and data(password and userid) everything before you issue token for that user,doing this validation in filter level is against the proper design patterns.

2)Validation - You can do it in filter level itself. It also helps you prevent from writing that validation logic individually in each and every controller methods or extra annotations.

Comment: Thank you @Rajkumar , but what will be the mission of the filter , if everything is done after

Comment: Filter just validates the request whether to pass the request to next level or not. This is actually a post-login scenario in your case. For login request, you just do nothing filter, once after you validate the login request, using the jwt token you provided the subsequent requests will come from the client, you can validate them in the filter itself.

Comment: Thank you RAJKUMAR .. that is really helping me